# MATLAB set specific default figure properties

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Is there a way to set very specific default properties for figure fonts and discriminate between tick font size, label font size, title font size, etc.. ?

I know I can set the default figure font properties by

```
set(0, 'DefaultAxesFontSize',14)
set(0, 'DefaultAxesFontWeight','bold')
```

But I'm looking for something like:

```
set(0, 'DefaultXTickLabelFontSize',10)
set(0, 'DefaultLegendFontSize',12)
% etc..
```

That would be very convenient. Thanks for any help!

Comment: [This information](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/creating_plots/setting-default-property-values.html#brb8fc3) may help

Comment: I found out that my approach was correct, but XTickLabel doesn't seem to be an object type, that's why it wasn't working.

Comment: Luis, thanks for the hint. I had already been on that site but implemented it the wrong way initially.

Comment: @Lisa - could you please post your solution (as an answer to yourself) and accept it, so that this question doesn't appear as unanswered anymore?

Answer (score 1):

```
clear all
close all

X=rand(10,1);
Y=rand(10,1);

figure(1)
plot(X,Y)
title('This is a figure','interpreter','latex','FontSize',30);
whitebg([1,0.89063,0.87891]) % Background
set(gca,'FontSize',21); % Font size
set(gca,'YTick',[0 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1])
set(gca,'XTick',[0 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1])
set(gca,'XColor',[0.38,0.10,0.10]) %Color of the axis X
set(gca,'YColor',[0.38,0.10,0.10]) %Color of the axis Y
xlabel('x','interpreter','latex','FontSize',30); % Using for instance latex fonts
ylabel('y','interpreter','latex','FontSize',30);
set(gca,'LineWidth',3)
```

Update:

To be default use something like this set(gca,'XTickLabelMode','auto'), set(gca,'XTickMode','auto')

Explanation: [How to reset XTickLabel to default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909880/how-to-reset-xticklabel-to-default)

Comment: Maybe you could include a figure to demonsrate this?

Comment: Dear @kkuilla I had misunderstood the question. Please see now. Daniel

Comment: Dear @Lisa I had misunderstood the question. Please see now.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for answering. In your initial post, you guided me to the MATLAB help page for setting default properties (as did Luis Mendo earlier in the comments), which was what I was looking for (except I haven't found the the specific expressions to address tick labels, etc). The answer you gave know doesn't configure default behaviour, though.

Comment: Hi Daniel. I want to alter the default behaviour, instead of setting the tick label configuration to default. The way to do this, I found out in the mean time, is actually with something like `set(0, 'DefaultXTickLabelFontSize',10)` (which is what I posted in the original question), except I need to find the right expression for `XTickLabel`, because `XTickLabel` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Lisa As I told you in the update, I think in this case you need twq steps (I dont know the reason exactly). The first step is to alter the default behavior of the XTICK such as in set(gca,'XTick',[0 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1]) and then keep this configuration as the default as in set(gca,'XTickMode','auto'). There must be some reason for this. THe only thing that I know is that Matlab seems to deal differently with plot properties and the container properties. Maybe there is some intersection in the behavior, but they are usually considered differently.